# slickgrid sort column with html link

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, slickgrid

I have slickgrid data similar with below:

```
[{"id": 1, "docno":"<a href='link10.php'>Link 10</a>"},
{"id": 2, "docno":"<a href='link2.php'>Link 02</a>"}]
```

It can filter and sort via data view, but the sort ordering incorrect due to exist of .
I'm thinking writing a comparer for it but have no ideal how to compare row 1 and row 2.
So far anytips for improve it?

Thks

Comment: The `docno` property should be a number, it shouldn't include the HTML. Then you can create a formatter for it to transform it into the HTML. That way the sorting should work without any special comparators.

Comment: Use `slick.formatter.js` to use HTML elements in your slickgrid

Answer (score 1):

As this was partially answered by both idbehold and Premshankar, here is the full answer to your question:

```
var docNoFormatter = function(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
  var docno = value ? value : "";
  return '<span><a href="link' + docno + '.php">' + docno + '</a></span>';
};

columns = [
  {id:"id", field:"id", name:"Document", formatter:docNoFormatter}
];
```

Pay attention to the fact that SlickGrid always require an `id` field with unique values. Also note that in my answer, there is no need for `slick.formatter.js` though if you want to have a better separation of your code and/or use some predefined SlickGrid formatters like for example `percent-complete-bar` you could use this file or even add your own formatters into it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply. Currently I'm developed a universal javascript initiator for slickgrid, technically my data is very dynamic and I can't preset docnoformatte as u mentioned. Data supply from PHP.

To balance sorting, and with dblclick open url I'm manage to solve it with my way:

php side:

```
$docno=$row["docno"]."<span class='hiddentcss'>".$row['id']."</span>";
```

in javascript:

```
...
columns=[{id..... cssClass="docnocss",sortable:true}],...
...

$(".docnocss").bind("dblclick",function(){
var url="http://www.sample.com?id=";
var id=$(this).children("span").html();
window.open(url+id);
});
```

css side:

```
.hiddentcss{
display:none
}


   .docnocss:hover,{
        color:black;
        text-decoration: underline !important;

    }

  .docnocss,  {
        color:blue;
        text-decoration: none;

    }
```

hope this help others people!
Ks